# Sprint Boot - Conexão dinâmica

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, datasource

tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida com Sprint Boot que atualmente se conecta a um único banco de dados Oracle usando as configurações do Application.properties.
Porém, preciso que essa aplicação se conecte com bancos de dados diferentes, dependendo das informações escolhidas na tela de login, ou seja, na tela de login o usuário vai escolher qual o BD que ele quer se conectar. Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

No próprio properties tu pode fazer a configuração de diversos produtos tais como bancos, filas e outras tecnolgias, mas vi que você comentou que o que define o tipo de conexão é interação do usuário.

Minha sugestão seria você configurar a sua aplicação para se conectar nos bancos ao iniciar e dentro da aplicação você poderia criar um serviço que será responsável por saber onde as coisas devem ser persistidas, só reforçando toda essa configuração de conexão é feita no arquivo de properties

Grande abraço.

Comment: Oi Diogo, obrigado pela resposta. Acredito que terei que seguir desta forma mesmo.